# Заполнение ListView фрагмента

Tags: android-sdk, android, android-fragment, listview

Здравствуйте!
Пытаюсь заполнить данными фрагмент листвью.
Программа запускается корректно, но когда открываю фрагмент там нет данных(показывает экран с моим TextView и надписью "Нет данных"), при дебаге видно, что пустой сам листвью, т.е. в адаптор данные поступили. Посмотрите код пожалуйста.

```
public class MyEmployeFragment extends Fragment {

    MyTask task;
    String employer_id;
    String employer_name;
    String str=null;
    // имена атрибутов для Map
    final String ATTRIBUTE_ID   = "p_id";
    final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "p_name";
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                                     Bundle savedInstanceState)  {

        task    = new MyTask();
        task.execute();

        // Creating view correspoding to the fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_employe, container, false);

        // Updating the action bar title
        getActivity().getActionBar();
        String[] userId = {"1","2","3"};

        String[] userName = {"Nadezhd","Vasya", "hardcore"};

        ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
                userId.length);
        Map<String, Object> m;
        for (int i = 0; i < userId.length; i++) {
            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_ID, userId[i]);
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, userName[i]);
            data.add(m);
        }

        // массив имен атрибутов, из которых будут читаться данные
        String[] from = {ATTRIBUTE_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME};
        // массив ID View-компонентов, в которые будут вставлять данные
        int[] to = {R.id.tw_employe_id, R.id.tw_employe_name};

        // создаем адаптер
        SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.list_item_employee,
              from, to);

        // определяем список и присваиваем ему адаптер
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_employee_list);

        listView.setAdapter(sAdapter);

    return v;
}

}
```

---

list _ item _ employe.xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/tw_employe_id" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/tw_employe_name"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

---

my _ employe .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lv_employee_list"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/tw_employe_name"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/empty">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/tw_employe_id"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MyEmployeFragment extends Fragment
```

Заменить на

```
public class MyEmployeFragment extends ListFragment
```

В описании Layout идентификатор ListView заменить на **[@android](/users/8445/android):id/list**

Соответственно в коде не искать ListView, а просто использовать метод getListView().

Обычный Fragment не умеет автоматически производить манипуляции с empty/list.

Comment: @Deadkenny большое спасибо за ответы! Лично Ваши, мне в который раз, помогают!
Все заработало.
Только почему, сейчас выводит только одну строку данных.
Т.к. я получаю  вот такой массив: 


        {"p_result":"ok","p_item":        [{"p_id":132,"p_name":"Николай","p_last_name":"Ереминко"},        {"p_id":133,"p_name":"Светлана","p_last_name":"Федорченко"}]}

Выводит в лист только : 133  Светлана  Федорченко

Comment: Для этого надо видеть код из MyTask

Comment: @Deadkenny @Override
       protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String s = "5ACACEC6-752B-4EFF-AA50-EEBE58A52113";
            HttpActivity _http = new HttpActivity("sd", "asd");
            _http.set_addr_protocol("abc");
            _http.add_param("query", "spr_employee_get");
            _http.add_param("p_guid", s);
            _http.send();

            employer_name = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_name");
            employer_id = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_id");
            employer_last_name = _http.getArrayParamValue("p_last_name");

Comment: onPre execute и post пустые

Comment: в целом переписал кучу кода, теперь проблема в том, как сначала загрузить данные, а потом только отобразить их. в методе onAttach прописал task.execute();
но смысл не поменялся

Comment: @Garf1eld http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/274-urok-135-loader-loadermanager-asynctaskloader.html Либо использовать LoaderManager. Он сохраняет состояние данных при изменении конфигурации.

Либо использовать setRetainInstance() и при каждом onViewCreated проверять если данные загружены - то не загружать по новой.

Либо использовать синглтон, который будет хранить загруженные данные.